# Guessing game loop

Tags: java, loops, counter

Here is the code for a guessing game I have made. My counter in not increasing past 1. I am passing the parameters choice and generatedNumber from a seperate controller class. Should the do while loop be in the controller class?

```
            public String startGuessingGame(int choice, int generatedNumber) {

        int count = 0;
        final int attempts = 4;
        String result = null;

            do {

                count++;

                if (choice == generatedNumber) {

                    result = "Attempt " + count + " "
                            + "- You have guessed the correct number!";

                }

                else if (choice > 50 || choice < 0) {

                    result = "Out of range. "
                            + "\nPlease choose a number between 1 and 50."; 

                }

                else if (choice > generatedNumber) {

                    result = "Attempt " + count + " " 
                            + " - You have guessed too high!";

                }

                else if (choice < generatedNumber) {

                    result = "Attempt " + count + " " 
                            + "- You have guessed too low!";

                }


                if (count == attempts) {

                    result = "You are out of guesses! The number was " + generatedNumber;

                }
            }

        while(count < attempts);

            return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually have a loop here. I don't see a for, while, or do-while statement anywhere.

Comment: Without a loop, there is no repetition. You have to have a loop. You should make sure you check the correct condition in the loop.

Comment: Post the code you have with a loop instead, makes more sense to help you with that since you definitely needs a loop

Comment: Apologies, edited code is above

Comment: My bad, I should have seen this earlier, you need to have you loop outside of the method `startGuessingGame` or let user make a new choice inside the method. right now there will be one choice and the method will count to 4 (for the same choice) and exit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop here.
You're looking for something like `while(count < attempts)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `count` a class variable (member) of your controller class and have your do/while loop in that class so that the `startGuessingGame` only handles the validation of the user choice. Something like this but the code is far from complete

```
public class SomeControllerClass() {
    final int attempts = 4;
    int count = 0;

    public void someMethod() {
        int choice = 0;
        do {
            choice = getChoice();
            count++;
            String text = otherClass.startGuessingGame(choice, generatedNumber);
        while (count < attempts);
    }
```

and the method only does validation

```
public String startGuessingGame(int choice, int generatedNumber) {
    String result = null;

    if (choice == generatedNumber) {
        result = "Attempt " + count + " "
                        + "- You have guessed the correct number!";
    } else if (choice > 50 || choice < 0) {
    //and so on
   return result;
}
```

Comment: I need to take choice as a parameter as it is being taken from a controller class

Comment: @GearoidSheehan Ok, one problem here is that your method behaves like it is part of a controller class so I guess there is not an easy fix.

Comment: @GearoidSheehan I have updated my answer with a new solution

Comment: @GearoidSheehan Any feedback on this?

Comment: I managed to get the count working using your solution, however each time the output was "You have guessed too low!" no matter what value was entered.

Comment: @GearoidSheehan It's hard for me to guess what is wrong but have you checked what values `startGuessingGame` gets called with each time, in the debugger or by adding a `System.out.println` in the beginning of the method?

Comment: fixed the issue after debugging, int choice = 0; was globally declared in the controller class but in the event handler method int choice = Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText()); was causing it be changed back to zero. Just edited to choice = Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText()); and works perfectly now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Incrementing the counter at the end before the `while` condition:

```
do{
    ...
    if (count == attempts) {

        result = "You are out of guesses! The number was " + generatedNumber;

    }
    count++;
}while(count < attempts);

return result;

...
```

Comment: This is causing the code to jump straight to "You are out of guesses!"